# javascript to launch only ONE window for a Java applet with a given URL

Tags: javascript, window, window.open

I need a javascript solution to launch only one window, with a Java Applet in it, for a given URL.  I found a solution posted here on Stack Overflow - 
here: [JavaScript window.open only if the window does not already exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528671/javascript-window-open-only-if-the-window-does-not-already-exist)

But it doesn't seem to work .. I get
Error: launchApplication.winrefs is undefined
Line: 29

I can't seem to post the code in this little box and make it look right below, 
so the code (my working code, plus the solution from above) 
is here:  http://pastie.org/833879

Where is the error?

As I understand it, the hash or array or whatever I use to store the called references to the windows opened this way will be lost if the calling window is closed.

Is there a way to make this work even if the calling window is closed and reopened?  To basically ask the browser: "Do you have a window open with the following URL?" and if so, "What is the reference to that window?" (so I can raise it).

Answer (score 0):

#### First Problem [Resolved]

I see that you're using `winRefs` in one spot, and later `winrefs`. It may just be the case that you need to uppercase the R on the second. It appears that you've got the lowercase version in your code a few times, even after line 29. Be sure to update all of them before testing again.

#### Second Problem

I just noticed that this line:

```
if ( typeof launchApplication.winRefs == undefined )
```

Will not return `true` if `.winRefs` is absent. Of course we want it to return true if the property is not found so we have to wrap `undefined` in quotes to get this working the way we want:

```
if ( typeof launchApplication.winRefs == "undefined" )
```

Comment: Thank you.  I hadn't caught that.  fixed it, now all the winrefs are "winRefs"... but still giving the same error.