# Determining wheter a window by window.open() is closed or not in javascript

Tags: javascript, window

Is thee a way for Determining wheter a window by window.open() is closed or not in javascript?
Following is a simple code for opening a window.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var win = window.open("test.htm")
</script>
```

When some event is fired. a event handler should determine a window is still opened.

```
if ( /* is a window alive */ )
    alert("window is still alive!");
else
    alert("window was closed!");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [`Window.closed` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.closed).

> This property indicates whether the referenced window is closed or not. [Read only].

Answer (score 0):

The code provided for this question seem to be more complete than simply checking for closed:
[JavaScript window.open only if the window does not already exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528671/javascript-window-open-only-if-the-window-does-not-already-exist)