# JavaScript: check for window exists && is/is not minimized

Tags: javascript, popup, window, exists

I want to be sure that any popup opened earlier not only exists, but is not minimized. An  [**earlier discussion**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528671/javascript-window-open-only-if-the-window-does-not-already-exist) talked about checking for the window's existence. I'm guessing (hoping!) that giving focus to an already-open window will restore that window if it's been minimized.

Is that the case, or no?

Thanks!

Comment: @Dr.Molle -- danke sehr!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do both, assuming 'window' is your reference to the tab or browser window you and detect focus and set it using these:

```
function detectFocus(state){
   return "Window is now "+state;
}
window.onfocus = function("in focus")
window.onblur = function("not in focus")
/*You then can set state with this method of window:*/
if(needToRestore==true){window.focus}
```